# Spring MVC - Read file from my controller

Tags: java, spring

I'm looking for a way to get a file placed in my WEB-INF directory from my controller. I need this file to validate my XML.

Here is my project architecture :

[image]

I need to get the rg19.xsd file from my Controller method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done that kind of thing myself, I usually use resources to do that, But I think you can autowire `ServletContext` and call

```
@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;

//inside controller:
new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/xsd/rg19.xsd"))
```

Give it a try and let me know

**Edit** for the comment:

By putting files inside main/resourses I access it by using @Value magic:

```
@Value("classpath:xsd/rg19.xsd")
Resource resourceFile;
```

After that, its easy to `getFile` from `resourceFile`

Comment: I can put the file in the resources folder. I'm just looking for a way to access and read the file

Comment: I'm curious to know if the first method worked or not?